# How do I auto login after registration in Django?

Tags: django

So, I'm trying to let the user be automatically logged in as soon as he/she registers. Here's my register function.

```
def register(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()

        return redirect('/main/inputuserinfo')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    return render(response, 'register/register.html', {'form' : form})
```

As I mentioned, I'd like to log the user in right after he/she registers, then redirect him/her to '/main/inputuserinfo'.
But I have no idea on how I can create it.
I very much appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can authenticate newly registered user like this

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate

if response.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user =  authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect..
```

Comment: Thanks. But would it be wrong if I put ```response``` instead of ```request``` since my function ```register``` has ```response``` as parameter?

Comment: Oh I've tried, and ```response``` totally works. Thanks :)

Comment: you can write response also if you have `response`  as parameter in your function but I would suggest you to pass `request` as a parameter since *you are sending here a request to the server* so it will be more readable and understandable.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer as well if it worked

Comment: Thanks. The tutorial I've been following has used ```response``` and that's why I chose it. If it doesn't make much difference, I'll stick to it for now, and change to ```request``` should any problem occurs :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username,password=raw_password)
            login(request,user)
            return redirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request,'signup.html',{'form':form})
```

you can do like this by using authenticate and login method

Comment: Thanks. But would it be wrong if I use ```response``` instead of ```request```?

Answer (score 1):

````
def register(response):
        if response.method == 'POST':
                form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
                if form.is_valid:
                form.save()
                request.session['user_id'] =   form.cleaned_data.get("id")
                 return redirect('/main/inputuserinfo')
        else:
               form = RegisterForm()

               return render(response, 'register/register.html', {'form' : form}) ```
````

Comment: save the user data in session and cookies too.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I exactly save the user data and cookies?

Comment: response.set_cookie('user_data', form.cleaned_data.get("id")+" "+ form.cleaned_data.get("first_name"))

Comment: you can only save data in session no need to save data in cookies